# Resetting GuildMember's Nickname | Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a nickname resetter to your original nickname.

Example: `!reset` --> Resets your nickname.

This is the code I currently have:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  switch (command) {

    case 'reset':
            
          


  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
case "reset":
    if (!message.member.nickname) return message.channel.send("You don't have any nickname set.");
    message.member.setNickname("").then(member => {
        message.channel.send("Your nickname has been reset.");
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        message.channel.send("Couldn't reset your nickname.");
    })
```